# Subdivide hexagon surface into equilateral triangles

Tags: modeling

I'm not very experienced with Blender and I'm looking for a way to subdivide a hexagonal face into triangles. Basically I want to turn this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

while having the ability to control the subdivision level.

I know I could build the hexagon by hand, triangle by triangle, but perhaps there's a quicker way?

Comment: Is that even possible? Blender can't subdivide N-Gons, which is any face with more vertices than 4.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You first have to subdivide your hexagon once by hand, you can do subsequent steps non-destructively using modifiers.

1. Poke the faces of your NGON hexagon from the menu *Faces > Poke Faces* (press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on Blender versions pre 2.69)
2. Eliminate every other radial edge so you end up with three quads
3. Add a *Subdivide* modifier set to *Simple*
4. Then add a *Triangulate* modifier
5. Adjust the subdivision level through the *Subdivide* modifier

[image: Hexagon Subdivide]

Answer (score 11):

It depends from the way you have made the base hexagon : the key point is to set its center.

If you start from a circle with 6 edges then

1. extrude <kbd>E</kbd>, then
2. scale 0 <kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>0</kbd> and
3. remove all doubles, then
4. you can subdivide as you want (here twice in 3).

[image]