# How can I sub divide an equilateral triangle into many smaller equilateral triangles

Tags: objects, subdivision-surface

The title just about sums it up how can I sub divide an equilateral triangle into many smaller equilateral triangles. I need all of the faces to be the same size and shape. Like a 2D pyramid made of many smaller 2D pyramids.

Comment: Related [Subdivide hexagon surface into equilateral triangles](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56353/subdivide-hexagon-surface-into-equilateral-triangles)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could not yet figure out how to do it procedurally or in a non destructive manner. In the meantime you can easily do it by hand.

There is an addon shipped by default with Blender called *Add Mesh: Extra Objects* that can activated in the *User Preferences* dialog

Start by opening *File > User Preferences > Addons* then search for `Extra` and activate the *Add Mesh: Extra Objects* addon.

Then in the *3D View* press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> > *Add > Mesh > Math Function > Regular Solid*.

By default it should already create a Tetrahedron, if not just pick it from the pulldown preset menu.

The just enter *Edit Mode*, select all faces, press <kbd>W</kbd> > Subdivide. Adjust Subdivision Number from the operator properties in the Toolshelf, or pressing <kbd>F6</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I thought that @Kahless wanted 2D?  For 2D you can add a mesh circle, set the number of vertices to 3.  Go into Edit mode, select the edges, press F to create a face.  Select the face and subdivide.

Comment: Cool that sounds good I'll be sure to test that method out. But the provided solution also worked for my needs.