# How would I subdivide a triangular face?

Tags: interface, subdivision-surface

I would like to subdivide a triangular face.

When I select the face in Edit Mode and click subdivide, I don't see any subdivisions. I have measurements visible and new numbers appear but no corresponding subdivisions.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80646/how-can-i-sub-divide-an-equilateral-triangle-into-many-smaller-equilateral-trian

Comment: You don't see this? http://i.imgur.com/VMc6VNn.png

Comment: Is the face actually *triangular*? How many vertices does it have before subdiv?

Comment: Exactly how did the triangular face come to be? Is this a newly created face, or is it a face in an already existing mesh? And what method were you using to try to subdivide it?

Comment: This is a face in an existing mesh with 3 vertices.  I then select Subdivide from the Tools palette with one straight cut.

Comment: Hi Greg - in response to the image. No, I don't see the subdivisions.  The number of labels edge info labels increase but no subdivisions appear.

Comment: This may be a case where I need to start over from scratch.  I am also finding that if I select a face, do a Shift-S and place the Cursor to the Selected face, that any primitive added cannot be selected after it is created.  It is certainly visible, but cannot be selected in object or edit mode.  Primitives are not  appearing in the tree view.  I'm wondering if this is a corrupt file.

Comment: "Primitives are not appearing in the tree view." if adding them is done just after snapping cursor to the face then it's most likely done in Edit mode and no new objects will appear in the Outliner as all added meshes will be part of edited object. "The number of labels edge info labels " can you include a screenshot before and after subdivision?